# PDO Exception: Could not find driver (PHP to MS Access)

Tags: php, database, pdo

I am trying to connect to a MS Access Db that I have made from my apache server using PHP. I keep coming up with the error "could not find driver". I have searched through just about every web page on the internet and have found nothing of importance. I have undocumented the parts of the php.ini file to allow the odbc drivers to work. I also have tried to list all of the working drivers using the PDO::getAvailableDrivers() code yet nothing shows up no matter how many drivers I undocument from the php.ini file. I've created the DNS connection and linked it to the database yet I'm not sure how to connect to it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your database connection code. Where is the `msaccess` database hosted? locally? externally? These are important pieces of information to us.

Comment: I actually figured it out. The problem was the MS access stopped hosting their odbc connection to php. So I used PDO on a 32 bit system with apache and php. Everything worked after that.

Answer (score 1):

For everyone else that needs an answer to this:

MS Access has stopped updating and hosting their odbc connection to php in 2010 (approximately). It will still work if you make sure you're using a 32-bit system. I'm now using 32-bit Apache and PHP. It works flawlessly now.

Comment: It's working fine to me and I'm working with 64-bit. You just need to enable the odbc extension for pdo.